# Grails NullPointer on list of DomainClass

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to call a DomainClass.list() and its throw a Nullpointer exception.

The domain class doesn't have relationship just Strings and booleans properties.

The code is like web page calls ajax > Update action > service method > SystemConfig.list()

And it throws nullpointer exception.

Other strange thing is when i call the method to show the edit page it works, but when i try to call the action to update it doens't.

I really doens't know what to do. I tryed to put the logic in the controller, the service (where it is now), to use criteria, and nothing works...

Domain class

```
class ConfiguracaoSistema {

boolean usarCatix
boolean usarRcb
String cnpjRcb
String nomeRcb
String senhaRcb
String enderecoServicosCatix
String ipCatix
String portaCatix

static constraints = {
    cnpjRcb nullable: true
    nomeRcb nullable: true
    senhaRcb nullable: true
    enderecoServicosCatix nullable: true
    ipCatix nullable: true
    portaCatix nullable: true
} 
}
```

Stacktrace

```
2015-02-09 16:05:07,053 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /CRM/usuario/update/21 - parameters:
usuarioCatix: 13
password: ***
catix: on
name: Admin
_catix: 
version: 2
email: contato@vitor.ninja
gu: null
username: Admin
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>  176 | $tt__update in org.catelani.crm.UsuarioController$$EP3onIQu
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter    in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter    in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1142 | runWorker   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run         in java.lang.Thread
```

Even if i do the code below it throws NullpointerException

```
UsuarioController {

     @Transactional
     def update(usuarioInstance) {

     ConfiguracaoSistema.list()

     }
}
```

Comment: please add at least the code of the domain class and the stacktrace (with relation to the code).

Comment: does it also crash if you do a `println ConfiguracaoSistema.list()`?  the controller and the domain are in the same package and you can be sure, that the right domain is used here not some other class? what grails version is this?

Comment: Yes, it crash with the println, the controler and the domain and in the same package, i just cut off this info from the code i pasted. There is just one class with this name so yeah, its the correct class.
Grails version is 2.4.3

Comment: It's probably because you have a null value for usarCatix or usarRcb. Since they both have primitive `boolean` type, there's no way to store null, only true or false, or something that's been configured to represent true or false in the database (e.g. 1 and 0). Hibernate will not assume that null should correspond to false (or 0 for int/long types with) because null means that there's no value and that's often very different from false. If you have nulls in those two columns use `Boolean` (and `Integer`/`Long` for numeric types) so it can be null or true or false.